# Can a Remote Desktop software prevent windows 10 keylogger from accessing what is typed on client computer during a session to a remote computer?

Tags: privacy, windows-10, keyloggers, remote-desktop

The “improve inking and typing” setting in Windows 10 allows Microsoft to send themselves processed samples of what is typed on a machine (not sure if it is processed to remove details as it’s typed such as in RAM somehow or at Microsoft after they received it).

Is this still applicable through an RDP session using certain Remote Desktop software either client based or web based Remote Desktop? Meaning, can windows diagnostics (Microsoft) grab what is typed on the keyboard of the client computer that is sent to the remote computer during an Remote Desktop session if the setting is turned on on the client computer, but turned off on the remote computer?

I was thinking maybe the Remote Desktop client/web client software diverts the keystrokes to the drivers of the remote computer, bypassing the client computer hopefully keeping it from accessing what is typed into the remote computer for obvious security purposes.

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't trust Microsoft then don't use their operating system.

Comment: You can disable “Improve Inking and Typing.”